# How to prevent write transactions while copying the Sqlite3 database file?

Tags: sqlite

Sqlite3 [recommends](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) using the Backup API to make a backup but also indicates that copying can be safe as long as there are no transactions in progress:

> The best approach to make reliable backup copies of an SQLite database is to make use of the backup API that is part of the SQLite library. Failing that, it is safe to make a copy of an SQLite database file as long as there are no transactions in progress by any process.

I'd like to use the approach of copying the database file, provided I can do this safely.

NB. I understand that the Backup API is the preferred option, but since Sqlite3 advertises atomic commits I believe this approach is viable, and am interested to know how to make this approach as safe as possible.

What SQL command or API can be used to completely lock the database such that would satisfy the "as long as there are no transactions in process" requirement?

Can an empty exclusive transaction (i.e. `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;` with no further statements), be used to achieve this, despite technically being a transaction?

Comment: "...as long as there are no transactions in progress by any process." seems pretty clear to me. Use at your own risk.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield would you agree `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE` can enforce that requirement?

Comment: On the contrary, it seems plain that `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE` violates that requirement.

Comment: Did you read https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html ?

Comment: And note that if you're using wal mode, just copying the main database file isn't enough. Really, the backup api **is** the simpler approach. Unless you're unfortunate enough to be using a language whose sqlite bindings don't provide it, of course.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield well this is exactly why I'm asking for clarification. An empty `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE` (with no writes of its own) would seem to protect the database from any write transactions (which makes it safe for copying according to the docs), and yet is also technically transaction (which could make it unsafe depending on interpretation). Given this transaction would *do no writes*, is this actually a safe approach?

Comment: @Shawn yes I read it. I understand that the Backup API (or `VACUUM INTO`) is the more correct way, and good point regarding wal mode. I'm still interested in the answer to this question: is there a safe way to lock the DB with an SQL command?

Comment: The docs make no distinction between transactions that perform writes and ones that don't. The only safety guarantee, according to the plain wording of the documentation, is that there exist "no transactions in progress". If you choose to infer that this actually means (but doesn't say) that there are "no *write* transactions in progress", then that's up to you.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I completely agree, that is what the plain reading of the docs imply. However, this is exactly why I'm asking here, in case an expert on SO knows more than what is written there. Logically it makes sense to me that a no-op transaction wouldn't violate the constraint (as I assume it would acquire a lock, but not put the database in a state where copying it could result in a corrupted backup), but due to that language, I'd like to try and confirm this one way or another.

Comment: The only other thing I know to tell you is you might check on the SQLite Nabble mailing list archive (don't have the link handy), and either see if you can find something from one of the developer team, or ask a new question.